# How to check if EditText (input type:number) is null?

Tags: android, null, android-edittext, isnull, isnullorempty

I have a problem,
I have an EditText element (input type is numbers only), and I am trying to check if the value is null when pressing a button.

My code:

```
    // Get the chosen number input
    EditText numberInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberPlainTextInput);
    int chosenNumber = Integer.parseInt(numberInput.getText().toString().trim());

    // Get the result text element to set it`s text
    TextView resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);

    // If input number field is not null
    if (**@number is not null@**) { **@Do something here@** }
```

I know how to do it on PHP but I am new to Java.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: plz try to post your log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TextUtils.isEmpty(numberInput.getText());`

Comment: If the app is crashing it's because you're maybe trying to parse a null object into `int`. One thing you can do is set an error to your `EditText` if the content is empty

Comment: Yeah I know I messed up the lines and @ADM just gave me his solution which seems to work perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first check for blank or null and then parse it .

```
EditText numberInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberPlainTextInput);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(numberInput.getText().toString().trim())) {
        int chosenNumber = Integer.parseInt(numberInput.getText().toString().trim());
        // Do your stuff here
    }
```